# Вывод массивов файл

Tags: python

пишу парсер на Питоне, одна из итераций выводит в консоль следующий результат, и теперь же хочу сохранить все это в файл csv, но пока что то не пойму как это сделать особенно в отношении значений которые в массиве, в какую сторону копать, как это можно сделать. Поля:

```
gender
profession
age
birth
category
salary
expirience['org', 'position', 'description', 'timeinterval']
education['edugov', ['spec']
keys['keys']
nationality
language['lang']


Мужчина
мастер, технолог, машиностроение, судостроение
36 лет
1983-04-11
Производство
20 000 руб.
[{'Организация': 'ОАО "СЕВМАШ"', 'Должность': 'Мастер станочных и слесарных работ', 'Описание работ': 'Управление произведственными рабочими', 'Продолжительность': '12 лет'}]
[{'Образовательное учреждение': 'Белорусская государственная орденов Октябрьской Революции и Трудового Красного Знамени сельскохозяйственная академия, Горки', 'Специальность': 'Технология-машиностроения, инженер'}]
[{'Ключевые навыки': 'опыт ручного труда, водитель В'}]
Россия
[{'Язык': 'Русский — Родной'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

csv не предполагает хранения структур. Можно сохранить массив как строку, а потом разобрать ее `split`ом. Я для хранения структур и сложных данных использую yaml.

```
import yaml

data = [
    {
        'a': 1,
        'b': [2, 3, 4],
        'c': {'c1': 5, 'c2': 6},
    },
    {
        'a': 7,
        'd': [8, 9],
        'e': {'e1': 'aaa', 'e2': 'bbb'},
    }
]

print(yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False))
print(yaml.safe_load(yaml.dump(data, default_flow_style=False)))
```

Результат:

```
- a: 1
  b:
  - 2
  - 3
  - 4
  c:
    c1: 5
    c2: 6
- a: 7
  d:
  - 8
  - 9
  e:
    e1: aaa
    e2: bbb

[{'a': 1, 'b': [2, 3, 4], 'c': {'c1': 5, 'c2': 6}}, {'a': 7, 'd': [8, 9], 'e': {'e1': 'aaa', 'e2': 'bbb'}}]
```